# Google Images API get_serving_url() download

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

How is it possible to download an image using `get_serving_url()` with a filename?
Example for url and parameter:
`http://[image-url]=d`

```
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/93uhV8K2yHkRuD63KJxlTi7SxjHS8my2emuHmGLZxEmX99_XAjTN3c_2zmKVb3XQ5d8FEkwtgbGjyYpaDQg=d
```

This downloads the image with `unnamed.jpg` as filename. I would like to get the orginal filename as well.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you used to generate the URL? Where is the original file stored?